# Django admin show who submitted the entry

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've a database of doctors. I want to be able to see in the admin panel under doctors who created a particular doctor entry. I've the following in my admin.py

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('user_permissions', 'groups')
    save_on_top = True
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'last_login', 'date_joined')

admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)


class DoctorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'specialization', 'education1', 'clinic', 'submitted_on', 'rating', 'netlikes')
    search_fields = ('name', 'id', 'specialization__name', 'clinic__name')

admin.site.register(Doctor, DoctorAdmin)
```

I want to have another column next to netlikes as 'submitted by' and would like to see the username of the person who created that doctor entry.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Doctor` model will need to have a field that stores this information, such as

```
submitted_by = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

You have to make sure to populate this information whenever you create a new instance of `Doctor`, probably using `request.user`. Then, in your `ModelAdmin`, you can just add this field to `list_display`.